# C++ strange output with cout and reverse_iterator

Tags: c++

I find a very strange output in C++ when I try to use vector's reverse_iterator to do a traverse. My code is simple and like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    vector<int>::reverse_iterator it = v.rbegin();
    cout << *it++ << " " << *it++;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 2 3. I can't figure out what happened in it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how long you've been doing C++, but again, Welcome to C++ :-) ...

**You have just entered the world of [Undefined Behaviors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)**

You should break your code down into:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    vector<int>::reverse_iterator it = v.rbegin();
    cout << *it;
    it++; 
    cout << " " << *it;
    return 0;
}
```

It works now... :-)

Let me explain give you a brief overview of what is happening in your original code...

This line

```
cout << *it++ << " " << *it++;
```

Whether the first `it` will be incremented before the second is unspecified.

Remember, post-increment operator returns a copy of the iterator and increments the original iterator. You had it twice in the same statement, So, what you were most likely having was that `it` was incremented twice before the latest copy was dereferenced first, then the former copy dereferenced second

Also see the beautiful answers to this Stackoverflow question
 [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: I am newcomer in C++, and now I know why I make a mistake. You really help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @Liberty, I am glad, I did :-), if your question has been resolved, you may mark it Answered